# Python Dict append list with given vars

Tags: python, dictionary

I trying to structure the data with dict with appending list, I tried using `defaultdict` but giving error.

```
data = 
"""
[{'transit01_net': '192.168.1.0',
  'transit01_subnet': '26',
  'transit02_net': '192.168.2.0',
  'transit02_subnet': '26',
  'transit03_net': '192.168.3.0',
  'transit03_subnet': '26',
}]
"""
output = {
  'transit01': [],
  'transit02': [],
  'transit03': []
}
```

I would like to get:

```
{
'transit01': ['192.168.1.0', '26', 'Transit01'],
'transit02': ['192.168.2.0', '26', 'Transit02'],
'transit03': ['192.168.3.0', '26', 'Transit03'],
}
```

I have tried following, but only able to print the first

```
for item in data:

      # Iterating the elements in list
      output['transit01'].append(item['transit01_net'])
      output['transit01'].append(item['transit01_subnet'])
      output['transit01'].append('Transit01')

      output['transit02'].append(item['transit02_net'])
      output['transit02'].append(item['transit02_subnet'])
      output['transit02'].append('Transit02')

      output['transit03'].append(item['transit03_net'])
      output['transit03'].append(item['transit03_subnet'])
      output['transit03'].append('Transit03')
```

Comment: You should give all relevant details, like what the error is, we shouldn't need to guess.

Comment: You data is a string of a list containing a dict, and your example code does not print anything. Please provide a minimal example for us to reproduce your problem, and specify what the desired outcome of that code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step through this. You want to get from this:

```py
data = 
"""
[{'transit01_net': '192.168.1.0',
  'transit01_subnet': '26',
  'transit02_net': '192.168.2.0',
  'transit02_subnet': '26',
  'transit03_net': '192.168.3.0',
  'transit03_subnet': '26',
}]
"""
```

To this

```py
{
'transit01': ['192.168.1.0', '26', 'Transit01'],
'transit02': ['192.168.2.0', '26', 'Transit02'],
'transit03': ['192.168.3.0', '26', 'Transit03'],
}
```

The former is a string that describes a literal data structure. Python gives you access to `ast` to lex and tokenize that into a python object for you.

```py
import ast
evald_data = ast.literal_eval(data)
```

From there you need to do the more difficult work of actually parsing the structure. Looks like you can split each key, though, and get what you need. Let's save off name of each field for now.

```py
result = {}
for d in evald_data:  # for each dictionary in the (single-item) list
    for k, v in d.items():
        name, key = k.split("_")
        result.setdefault(name, {})[key] = v

# this should give you
expected = {
    {'transit01': {'net': '192.168.1.0', 'subnet': '26'},
    {'transit02': {'net': '192.168.2.0', 'subnet': '26'},
    {'transit03': {'net': '192.168.3.0', 'subnet': '26'}
}
assert result == expected
```

From there it's pretty simple stuff. I'd posit that you probably want a tuple instead of a list, since these values' order seem to matter (sorting them isn't just bad, it's *incorrect*).

```py
final_result = {k: (v['net'], v['subnet'], k.title()) for k,v in result.items()}
expected = {
    'transit01': ['192.168.1.0', '26', 'Transit01'],
    'transit02': ['192.168.2.0', '26', 'Transit02'],
    'transit03': ['192.168.3.0', '26', 'Transit03'],
}
assert final_result == expected
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, you are correct, as I would like to keep the order same, so tuple would better.. thank you. Once I get the data in structure, I can use for loop to access the value from the keys correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

**Ex.**

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [{'transit01_net': '192.168.1.0',
  'transit01_subnet': '26',
  'transit02_net': '192.168.2.0',
  'transit02_subnet': '26',
  'transit03_net': '192.168.3.0',
  'transit03_subnet': '26',
}]

output = defaultdict(list)
temp = 1
for x in data[0]:
    key = x.split("_")[0]
    output[key].append(data[0][x])
    sub_key = "transit0{}_subnet".format(temp)
    if x == sub_key:
        output[key].append(key.capitalize())
        temp+=1

print(dict(output))
```

**O/P**

```
{'transit01': ['192.168.1.0', '26', 'Transit01'], 'transit02': ['192.168.2.0', '26', 
'Transit02'], 'transit03': ['192.168.3.0', '26', 'Transit03']}
```

Comment: thanks Bharatk, surely this looks simple with defaultDict.